# How to write code for choosing date of birth in JSP form

Tags: html, jsp

can any one suggest how to write code for taking his/her date of birth as an input for user an store it in Database.

Comment: SO will not help you on this.

Comment: start learning j2ee if you want to do that with java

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>..................</title>
<script language="javascript">
function doCheck()
{
var s1=document.getElementByName("DateofBirth");
if(s1.value == "")
{
alert ("enter the DateofBirth");
s1.focus();
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="store.jsp">
<input type="text"  NAME="DateofBirth" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

save it as abc.jsp
then create new file

```
  <%
        try {
    String s1 = request.getParameter("DateofBirth");
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connectioncon1=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"username", "password");
            Statement st = con1.createStatement();
           System.out.println("insert into userregistrations values('" + s1 "')");
            st.executeUpdate("insert into userregistrations values('" + s1 + "')");
            out.println("Congrats!!Now, You have sucessfully registered");
             }
        catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
        }
  %>
```

save the file as store.jsp